# How to populates an existing object instance with values from JSON

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to copy the example from this link.
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PopulateObject.htm

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Account
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "title")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int MainContactId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }

    }

        Account account = new Account
        {
             Id = 0,
             Name = "xxx",
             MainContactId = 0,
             DateCreated = new DateTime(),
             DateUpdated = new DateTime(),

        };

        string json = @"{ 
           'Name': 'Help',
           'MainContactId': 0,
        }";

       Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, account);
       Console.WriteLine(account.Name);
```

Name doesnt seem to change. What am i missing from the example.

Comment: You need us to provide the definition of the Account class you are using in order to have a [MCVE].

Comment: The code works for me (Core 3.1 Console App). Can't see your Account class, but I presume it's straightforward.

Comment: I tried the exact code you posted and it works as expected.  Could it be the json you are getting is different?

Comment: Must be something in my setup. That is the exact example i am using.

Comment: The only thing i see that could cause this is the DataMember(Name="title") what happens if you remove the "Name" portion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Account` class, you have configured the `Name` property with a `[DataMember(Name = "title")]`.  This will cause the serializer to try to match it with a `title` property in the JSON.  However, your JSON does not contain a `title` property; it contains a `Name` property.

Here are a couple of possible solutions:

1. Remove the `Name = "title"` from the `[DataMember]` attribute on the `Name` property:

   ```
   [DataMember]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   ```

   Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WDTJrU

   **OR**
2. Change the JSON so that it has a `title` instead of a `Name`:

   ```
   string json = @"{ 
      'title': 'Help',
      'MainContactId': 0,
   }";
   ```

   Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WTnOIS